# When is a Viewmodel's constructor called in Android?

Tags: android, viewmodel, android-lifecycle

I'm going through this codelab: https://developer.android.com/codelabs/android-lifecycles#6
It explains how to use SavedStateHandle in a ViewModel to survive process death. The constructor of the ViewModel is as below:

```
    private SavedStateHandle mState;

    public SavedStateViewModel(SavedStateHandle savedStateHandle) {
       mState = savedStateHandle;
    }
```

And the viewmodel is initialized in the Activity as follows:

```
    mSavedStateViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(SavedStateViewModel.class);
```

When is the ViewModel's constructor called? And how does the Viewmodel get the `savedStateHandle` parameter of the ViewModel?

**Edit:**

I found the answer to my question through this blogpost:
https://www.rockandnull.com/viewmodel-savedstate/

It says that if the`SavedStateHandle` is the only parameter in our viewmodel's constructor the `by viewModels` delegate provides it to the viewmodel automatically.

However,
If we have a combination of custom parameters that provided by the dependency injection framework(Hilt) e.g: the repository, a couple of other runtime arguments e.g: selected category ID and the SavedStateHandle to help us survive the process death in the viewmodel's constructor - How can we provide all those parameters to the factory?

Please post a small example for my understanding

Answer (score 5):

The Codelab you are following is to make you understand a specific Concept instead of
the whole code . No implementation is provided by them regarding your doubt , which is , how does the ViewModel get it's parameters ?

---

OverView :
Due to certain internal implementation of ViewModel , you cannot pass arguments to the ViewModel directly , instead you need to create a third class which provides the parameters to the ViewModel.

---

Answer to your doubt :

There are two approaches via which a ViewModel can get it's parameters :

1. **Non-Dependency Injection Way** :
   Here you create a class extending  ViewModelProvider.Factory . In your code , here you can see :

```
  mSavedStateViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(SavedStateViewModel.class);
```

Here a default class is created wherein , no arguments are passed .This is done for the purpose of initialization , which is an incomplete way given in the codelab to express the needs . You can get a good amount of knowledge on the same concept via this article :

> https://medium.com/koderlabs/viewmodel-with-viewmodelprovider-factory-the-creator-of-viewmodel-8fabfec1aa4f

2. **Dependency Injection Way** :
   Now , this is the simplest way to implement a ViewModelProviders if you know DI framework Hilt . Here you just need to annotate your ViewModel with @ViewModelInject and you are done .The DI framework in the backgroun will create a ViewModelFactory instead of you doing it .This is a sample code of how you provide parameters to ViewModel using Hilt :

```
class SampleViewModel @ViewModelInject constructor(
                     @Assisted private val savedStateHandle: SavedStateHandle) : ViewModel() { }
```

Comment: I have debugged the app from the codelab. It's constructor is being called even though I'm not passing any factory. How is that possible? Who passes the SavedStateHandle to the constructor?

Comment: Can you share the link to the application ? Did you run the application locally on Android Studio ? Because the github link to the code mentioned in the codelab mentions some usecases and their solution , there is no full fledged solution like a complete application

Comment: You can download the source code from here: https://developer.android.com/codelabs/android-lifecycles#1

Comment: Also please look into the Edit section of the question

Comment: Happy you got your answer .

Comment: Can you elaborate more on your  edit ? I am not getting the exact content you want to know . ViewModel provides you the extra functionality of caching your data for screen orientation , so to provide these functionality , the developers had to find a way , wherein this was the one they found out .  We all android developers have to go through such instances a lot in our career,  I hope you understand

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239540/discussion-between-neeraja-gandla-and-karunesh-palekar).